# xelatex xdvipdfmx error, cannot proceed with font

Tags: fonts, xetex, xdvipdfmx

This problem has confused me for a while.
I set the mainfont garamond in my `tex` file:

```
\setmainfont{Garamond}
```

And it runs perfectly in my Windows laptop.

However, I use it on my Mac and there is an error:

> xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without the font:
>   `/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Garamond`

I check `/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/` folder and the `Garamond` is there. But the `xelatex` compiler just complains about the font.

I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Now I fixed this problem.
I use `fondu` to extract `Garamond.ttf` from the font suitcase file. Then change it to

```
\setmainfont{Garamond.ttf}
```