# Why can't Xetex find my font

Tags: fonts, xetex

I've tried following the instructions at
[How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37251)
But, when I try to run the small file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\myfont{Lucida Calligraphy}
\begin{document}

Hello
\myfont Hello

\end{document}
```

I get the following error

```
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without the font: /Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Lucida Calligraphy
```

The font is in that directory.  I found the following similar request [xelatex xdvipdfmx error, cannot proceed with font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272677/22413) But I'm not finding the provided answer very helpful: I don't know what `fondu` is, nor, even if I did have this *utility(?)*, I don't know how to use and am very nervous about tinkering in a library which is not specific to the user.

Comment: You are on a Mac? What kind of font is Lucida Calligraphy? Examples: opentype, truetype, truetype collection, type1 etc. There are also things like `.dftont`s and font suitcases. If it is an older Mac font, it may be using the resource fork. You can use `fondu` to extract the fonts into usable format. You don't change anything in the Library, though. You use a copy. I am not sure that XeTeX would be able to use such a font out-of-the-box, though. I've done this and then used the fonts as traditional TeX/pdfTeX fonts, but that means creating the support files.

Comment: If it is a suitcase and it contains a `.ttf`, use Finder to copy the font somewhere you can play with it. Tinkering in `/Library` is not like tinkering in `/System/Library` but, still, there is no reason to make yourself unnecessary trouble easily avoided. [I *think* you could copy it at the command line with OS X these days, but I'm *not* certain. You did not used to be able to except by using a special version of the commands. It is extremely easy to lose the resource fork containing a font, if that is where it is.)

Answer (score 4):

Some of the Microsoft fonts are Font Suitcases, an old format which embeds TrueType fonts into the resource fork.  XeTeX can't read these directly, but it's easy to extract the TTF files from the suitcases.  I used the application in this StackOverflow answer. It works well.

[Using OS 9 resource fork fonts in CSS with @font-face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412462/using-os-9-resource-fork-fonts-in-css-with-font-face)