# XeTeX doesn't find a font

Tags: fonts, xetex, lyx, hebrew, xdvipdfmx

I tried to run a file at Hebrew with LyX (at XeTeX), and here is the message I get:
`xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without the font: C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/type1/public/culmus/DavidCLM-MediumItalic.pfa`

But the file is there! (at this specific address)
How can I fix this?

Thank you!

(P.S. at pdflatex it's work fine, but I need to use XeTex)

Comment: Is it the same case? (I don't expect this to make a difference since most Windows file systems are not case-sensitive, but still worth checking). Does the file have correct permissions?

Comment: @scottkosty what do you mean when you say: "Is it the same case?" (but I think the answer is yes... and yes - the file have the correct permissions)

Comment: you shouldn't use type1 fonts with xelatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I use .pfa files... And if it's not good, how do I change it? I'm using LyX...

Comment: .pfa is a type1 format (see the folder the file is in). And you should use  fontspec and .ttf oder .otf font.

Comment: @heblyx I mean case as in "aBc" might be considered different from "abc".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, so how can I change it? Can you explain me? how do I use the .ttf file? (LyX automatically takes the .pfa files....)

Comment: @scottkosty, Yes , I write the file at the right way....

Comment: @heblyx OK, you might also want to check the file permissions, but I don't know how to do that on Windows. More importantly, if I were you I would give a minimal example (you can export to LaTeX and post that) and follow whatever advice Ulrike suggests.

Comment: @scottkosty it have the same permissions of other fonts because they are all at the same folder

Answer (score 3):

The Culmus fonts, including David CLM, are available from [the Culmus Project](http://culmus.sourceforge.net/).

XeTeX supports modern desktop fonts and Unicode, and I highly recommend that’s what you use.  If you really do want to use legacy fonts instead, Culmus links to [Iddo Samet’s package for MikTeX on Windows](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~sameti/tex/culmusmiktex.html), and there is also [the `culmus-latex` package](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/culmus-latex/).

Unfortunately, `\usepackage[hebrew]{babel}` with `fontspec` is broken (The version of `hebrew.ldf` included with babel 3.22 was last updated in 2005 and only supports obsolete 8-bit LHE fonts.) but [`polyglossia`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/polyglossia/polyglossia.pdf) works just fine.  Always save your source as UTF-8 when using XeTeX or LuaTeX.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=4in, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase, Ligatures = TeX }
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Taamey David CLM}[
  Script = Hebrew ,
  Language = Hebrew ]

\begin{document}
\section{בראשית}
\textbf{בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית}
 בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃ 
וְהָאָ֗רֶץ הָיְתָ֥ה תֹ֙הוּ֙ וָבֹ֔הוּ וְחֹ֖שֶׁךְ עַל־פְּנֵ֣י תְה֑וֹם וְר֣וּחַ אֱלֹהִ֔ים מְרַחֶ֖פֶת עַל־פְּנֵ֥י הַמָּֽיִם׃ 
וַיֹּ֥אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֖ים
\textit{יְהִ֣י א֑וֹר}
 וַֽיְהִי־אֽוֹר׃ 
וַיַּ֧רְא אֱלֹהִ֛ים אֶת־הָא֖וֹר כִּי־ט֑וֹב וַיַּבְדֵּ֣ל אֱלֹהִ֔ים בֵּ֥ין הָא֖וֹר וּבֵ֥ין הַחֹֽשֶׁךְ׃ 
וַיִּקְרָ֨א אֱלֹהִ֤ים ׀ לָאוֹר֙ י֔וֹם וְלַחֹ֖שֶׁךְ קָ֣רָא לָ֑יְלָה וַֽיְהִי־עֶ֥רֶב וַֽיְהִי־בֹ֖קֶר י֥וֹם אֶחָֽד׃
\end{document}
```

[image: In the Beginning, ....]

You could, if you prefer, select the language with the `numerals = hebrew` and `calendar = hebrew` options to get Hebrew numbers and dates.

Since the sample I picked included taamim, I used the [Taamey David CLM](http://culmus.sourceforge.net/taamim/index.html) font here, but for anything in Modern Hebrew, you wouldn’t need that and could substitute David CLM.

Addendum: `\babelprovide[import]{hebrew}` works with Babel 3.27, but not earlier.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer, or a lead for an answer.

I noticed that a `.pfa` David CLM font is *not* distributed with the Culmus project, as you can verify at the [project website](https://sourceforge.net/projects/culmus) (by downloading the archive and seeing the file list). Some *other* fonts do have `.pfa`s in the distribution archive, such as DrugulinCLM for example.

I'm also noticing you're trying to run `xdvipdfmx`. That does not sound like something that should happen when `xelatex` is generating a PDF - there shouldn't be any DVI files (which usually end up as PostScript in the end).

So, one of two things: Either you get your MikTeX to generate a `.pfa` for David CLM (is that even doable? I'm not sure), or make sure you are actually running xelatex and without a `-no-pdf` switch or something like that.

If `xelatex` does indeed use `.pfa`s for PDFs, for some reason, also try the advice in an answer to this question: [xelatex xdvipdfmx error, cannot proceed with font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272671/xelatex-xdvipdfmx-error-cannot-proceed-with-font?rq=1) .